# ImagePicker from external source and not photo album

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm looking for a custom control I can put in a UIViewController that has the functionality of `UIImagePicker` (displaying thumbnails, enable `multiselect` etc.) but display images from "the server" (a given array of images)

All the `ImagePickers` I find work directly on the albums as an alternative to `UIImagePicker`

Does anyone know a nice solution?

Comment: Why not choose an image picker of your liking, and customise it according to your needs? You simply change it's data source. Instead of Using `ALAssetsLibrary`, you create a custom source, and load images asynchronously with `SDWebImage` (or other library). You will need to store URLs of your images somewhere though, to load those images.

Comment: well... I'm looking for one that it is easy to do. Some of them got the ALAssetLibrary encapsulated deep...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib called "JPImagePickerController"
https://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController

You will make your own DataSource which will take your images which could be provided from disk or bundle